# call jquery document.ready function inside another jquery or javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one problem
I am trying to call document.ready() function inside another JavaScript function but when I am calling it, it says "function is not defined

Here is my code :
this is first function that is document.ready() function

```
$(document).ready(function ExpandMessageBox() {// this is my document.ready function. I have given the name of it as "ExpandMessageBox"}
```

this is another regular JavaScript function in which I am trying to call above function

```
function ShowMessageBox() {
    ExpandMessageBox();}
```

But this is giving me an error as :
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ExpandMessageBox is not defined"

Where I am doing wrong...
Please Help

Tons of thanks in advance

Comment: u will have to define ExpandMessageBox outside the function scope of the ready() function for it to be accessible by the ther function

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `ExpandMessageBox` function in the common scope. Something like this:

```
function ExpandMessageBox() {
  //your staff
}
function ShowMessageBox() {
  ExpandMessageBox();
}
$(document).ready(ExpandMessageBox);
```

Comment: I am calling $('div.Messageheader').click(function()), for that I have to put this code inside $(document).ready() function....
If I removed the $(document).ready() then, the click event of div not firing

Comment: So what a problem to put `$('div.Messageheader').click(function())` instead of my code comment `//your staff` to achieve what you want? Or what am I missed?

Comment: yes...initially I did this only...
but the click even does not fire..
So I searched for that...and I found that..
this code should be inside of $(document).ready(); function.

Comment: if you need just call click event on that element, you can `$('div.Messageheader').trigger('click')`

Comment: Can you please explain me how to use this???
I Mean how "$('div.Messageheader').trigger('click')" will call the function???
should I write the "onclick" event for that div???

Comment: `$('div.Messageheader').trigger('click')` will fire `click` event on the `'div.Messageheader'` element, so all of your listeners of that click will be fired too

Comment: I solve it by another way...
by calling inline "Onclick" event for div...
actually I know its a bad practice ...But...here I cant do anything...
Its working now as I wanted...
Thanks a lot for your contribution..